# React Hooks : TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am trying to extract value in React hooks but in meantime when I console `customer` I got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null` I don't know what issue have in my code . I am new to React Hook could someone please help me how to solve this problem .

Thanks

**When I console Customer , I am getting this result**

[Result View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAkCs.png)

**When I console customer.firstName**

It give me error

**Code**

```
 const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
  async function fetchMyAPI() {
    let response = await fetch(
      `/api/requirements/find?customerId=${item.customerId}`
    );
    response = await response.json();
    console.log(response);
    setCustomer(response);
  }

  useEffect(async () => {
    fetchMyAPI();
  }, []);
```

**In return function**

```
{console.log(customer.firstName)}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error makes sense, you are using `Object notation` to reach the value belonging to something that is not an object.

Just set your initial-state as an empty object to resolve your console error:

```
 const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({});
```

Overall code:

```
const Customer = () => {
 const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(null);
  async function fetchMyAPI() {
    let response = await fetch(
      `/api/requirements/find?customerId=${item.customerId}`
    );
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setCustomer(data);
  }

  useEffect(async () => {
    fetchMyAPI();
  }, []);

  return(
    <div>
       <h4>{customer.firstName}</h4>
       <h4>{customer.lastName}</h4>   
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Error is gone but when I console an value of `cusotmer` it give me undefined value

Comment: @jonny what does `console.log(response)`; return in the fetch API function? From your OP it sounds like you're calling console.log() in return?

Comment: I need to extract value of customer like `firstName` and `lastName`

Comment: I have attached image for it , could you please check it

Comment: @jonny gotcha! I've updated my code above, let me know if that works for you,

Comment: This answer would benefit from explaining why the value is `null`, such as going into detail about how the `useEffect()` callback is called after the first render and not before

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial state as blank object like below...

```
const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({});
```

OR 
You may set the default structure of object like below...

```
const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({firstName: '', lastName: ''});
```